# asp.net get Strongly Typed from string

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, strong-typing

My error code:

```
string model = "Content";
Type stype = Type.GetType("mvc.Models." + model);
ViewPage<stype> vp = new ViewPage<stype>();
```

Of course it error when compiling, but it clearly show what i'm thinking. Can i do this?

Comment: Eh, i see code here, not an error code...

Comment: i can not compile it, so it error or not?

Error 1 The type or namespace name 'stype' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Well, reading your code, are you sure there's a 'mvc.Models.Content' type available in your project?

Answer (score 2):

That function `GetType` needs an [assembly-qualified name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx), not just the namespace as you have provided.

Comment: I don't think so, because i can do this without error

Models.Content c = (Models.Content)Type.GetType("mvc.Models.RSSContent").InvokeMember("", BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, null, null);

RSSContent inherit from Content

Comment: I'm not certain but what you are trying to do may be outside the scope of the language constructs. It seems that when you code literally the Type, whether as a type dec or a explicit cast, it seems to work. I suspect the compiler does not like defining an explicit Type from a runtime evaluated type variable and that is why you get the build message.